# Elasticsearch Nest, parent/child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

can you help me out to define a parent/child relationship using `NESTclient` for elasticsearch?
my code looks like this:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "type_properties", DateDetection = true,.....)]
public class Properties{....}
```

---

```
[ElasticType(Name = "type_sales", DateDetection = true, , ParentType = "type_properties")]
public class SalesHistory{....}
```

I defined the parentType, but I don't see this sales documents related to a parent property.

```
{
  "_index": "testparentchild",
  "_type": "type_sales",
  "_id": "dVd1tUJ0SNyoiSer7sNA",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "salesRecId": 179504762,
    "salesPrice": 150000,
    "salesDate": "2003-04-07T00:00:00",
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The attribute based mapping is deprecated since all the possible mapping possibilities cannot be expressed that way.

See 
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs

How to properly apply a mapping for your type.

Comment: Thanks!, I took a quick look and I think I got it. Thanks again.